# Почему не подключаются стили в index.html на локальном сервере

Tags: html, css

С помощью node.js открыл сервер, почему на нем не отображаются стили, хотя если просто открыть в браузере index.html то все стили отображаются верно, в чем проблема?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "style.css" >
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id = "form" action="">
        <input id = "input" autocomplete="off"/><button>Send</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Нужно добавить обработчик этих самых файлов в файле сервера. Погядите [здесь](https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/4.4.php),  [здесь](https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/static-files.html) и в целом [здесь](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%85+%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2+node.js)
Здесь виноват ваш сервер

Comment: Проверьте правильно ли указан путь к css и умеет ли ваш сервер обрабатывать запрос на css. Сбросить кэш браузера. Откройте инспектор браузера и посмотрите запросы ответы

Comment: Сделал app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/style.css')); почему то все равно не видит. До сих пор ошибка because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: @Марьяна теперь в html попробуйте дописать перед style.css еще dirname. напрмиер static/style.css или static/static/style.css. Смотря где у вас style.css лежит. В моем сервере .css лежал в static, а в href нужно было писать static/static/style.css

Comment: @Марьяна и проверять лучше в режиме инкогнито.

Comment: @Марьяна я бы на вашем месте поискал инфу, как добавить обработку статических файлов не по одному, а все что в директории static(или аналогичной)